# Is there any reliable way to determine a user's location from their Internet connection?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, geolocation, location

I have created a Business Management System which is to be used by retailers with or without multiple sites.

It is important that a logged in user identifies his/her location, or site, so that the system can perform site related tasks automatically.

I currently have a database of locations which includes an `IP Prefix` field, when the user goes to the log in page it looks for the first 5 digits of the current IP address, then:

- If start of current IP matches a stored record it assumes user is at
  that site.
- If no IP matches then it asks the user which site they're in and asks them to update the IP.

This basic, and manual check works when the sites are a fair distance away or are on different ISPs for certain, the update is usually only required after a router restart and I've been using the system myself for about 4 years with no issues... BUT... I am not confident with it, so my question is; is there a better solution?

I realise the IP address is probably not the way as the best that gives me is the location of their ISP, but that's not what I need.

In case it matters I am using ASP.NET coding in VB

Also, should mention, I'm looking for desktop based application, not mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to rely on user input for this one.  It's impossible (or at least, very very difficult) to know whether a user is using a proxy or not, and if they are you have no way of knowing where they really are.  This is right and proper; would you trust every website you access with that kind of information?  I sure as hell wouldn't.

Comment: Reluctantly I am having to use this method. It's not the end of the world!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the IP address to give you 100% reliable location data if your clients connect over the internet (they could be going through a proxy or as you said you might just get the ISP's IP address)

Your best bet is to use javascript to get the users geolocation: [W3 Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

[More complex example on html5demos](http://html5demos.com/geo)

Comment: Hmm, I'd be happy to use that but it won't work on my machine!

Comment: Can you define "won't work"? Are locations disabled in your browser? Does it give incorrect results?

Comment: It just says "Cannot Determine Location" I'll check into browser settings, using Chrome if that's ay help?

Answer (score 0):

No, of course it is not possible to reliably locate an user by IP Adress.
That adress can be faked, so the base of your info is not reliable.

Comment: I know that, I said so in my question! My question is: 'Is there a better solution?'

Comment: Yes, let the user choose his country, like all web pages do, since 10 years